# How to map key and value data to text fields in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple JSON that has a key and a value, both have different values. I want to show each key and value on a view, am not sure how to go about it. This is my json

```
[
    {
        "key": "CLT",
        "value": "21"
    },
    {
        "key": "HEM",
        "value": "3"
    },
    {
        "key": "LIP",
        "value": "4"
    },
    {
        "key": "QNS",
        "value": "853"
    },
    {
        "key": "SAT",
        "value": "24202"
    },
    {
        "key": "SHV",
        "value": "229"
    },
    {
        "key": "SNC",
        "value": "196"
    },
    {
        "key": "VPL",
        "value": "4"
    }
]
```

this is my model

```
export class PTIDS {

  key: string;
  value: number;
  
}
```

I want to be able to map them in html like

```
<tbody *ngFor="let central of Centrals">
            <tr>
              <th>CLT(show key here)</th>
              <th>central.CLT(SHOW value here)</th>
            </tr>
           <th>HEM(show key here)</th>
              <th>central.HEM(SHOW value here)</th>
            </tr>
            <th>LTP(show key here)</th>
              <th>central.LTP(SHOW value here)</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the expected UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to  be fixed is model. PTIDS value type is `number` but in your code it is `string`. Instead of **"**20**"**, it should be 20.

Here is the working solution:

**app.component.ts**

```
centrals: PTIDS[] = [
{
  key: "CLT",
  value: 21
},
{
  key: "HEM",
  value: 3
},
{
  key: "LIP",
  value: 4
},
{
  key: "QNS",
  value: 853
},
{
  key: "SAT",
  value: 24202
},
{
  key: "SHV",
  value: 229
},
{
  key: "SNC",
  value: 196
},
{
  key: "VPL",
  value: 4
}
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let central of centrals">
  <tr>
    <th>{{central.key}}</th>
    <th>{{central.value}}</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**Update 1: (Updated code as per UI provided in screenshot)**

**html**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="box" *ngFor="let central of centrals">
 <div>{{central.key}}</div>
 <span>{{central.value}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

.box {
  background-color: orange;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

[image]

Here is the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-paper-7p2ur?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) link.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, provide an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) in order to be easier to reproduce it. Please try something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let central of Centrals">
   <span>{{central.key}}</span>
   <span>{{central.value}}</span>
</div>
```